# Solution to Schrodinger equation with non-Schwartz initial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

For $\xi_0\in\mathbf{R}^n$ compute the solution of the Schrodinger equation with initial data
$$
i\partial_tu-\Delta u=0 \text{ in } (0,t)\times\mathbf{R}^n\\
u(0,x)=e^{i\xi_0\cdot x} \text{ for all } x\in\mathbf{R}^n.
$$
Give an interpretation of the solution.

The only way that I know of finding the solutions to the Schrodinger equation is by taking the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ of the equation, solving it for $\hat{u}$, then using the convolution of the transform of the initial data with the transform of the complex heat kernel (Schrodinger kernel?). So when I try to do that I get this far.

$$
\mathcal{F}\{u(t,x)\}(k)=e^{i|k|^2t}\mathcal{F}\{e^{i\xi_0\cdot x}\}
$$

My issue now is that the initial data is not Schwartz, and so its Fourier transform does not exist. When I try to take the Fourier transform, I have to evaluate a circular function at $\pm\infty$, which doesn't make sense to me.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Tom

Comment: A wave function is supposed to be square integrable at every $t$ with a value of 1. Sounds like a strange exercise.

Comment: @T.A.E.: It is common in PDEs to consider the Schrödinger equation in the tempered distributional setting.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : It's not physical unless the solution is a unit vector in $L^{2}$ for all $t \ge 0$. So asking for an interpretation seems strange. "Interpretation" in what sense?

Comment: @T.A.E.: See my answer below for my interpretation of the word "interpretation". :-)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : My idea of an interpretation would be a physical interpretation, not a Mathematical description.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

The Fourier transform is defined for all tempered distributions. In this generalized sense you have 
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x\to k}\left(e^{i\xi_0\cdot x}\right)=(2\pi)^{d}\delta(k-\xi_0), $$
where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

As for the interpretation, try thinking at the result of applying a Galilean transformation to the initial datum $u_0(x)=1$.

Note 1: A Galilean transformation, aka "Galilean boost", is the map that sends the initial datum $u_0(x)$ to $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{k\to x}\left( \hat{u}_0(k+\xi_0)\right).$$

Note 2: I am using the following convention for the Fourier transform: 
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x\to k}(f(x))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot k}\, dx.$$

Comment: Thanks! So can I say
$$ 
\mathcal{F}\{u(t,x)\}=e^{i|k|^2t}(2\pi)^n\delta(k-\xi_0)\\
=\mathcal{F}\{\Gamma(t,x)\}\mathcal{F}\{e^{i\xi_0 \cdot x}\}\\
=\mathcal{F}\left\lbrace \int_{\mathbf{R^n}}\Gamma(t,x-y)e^{i\xi_0\cdot y} dy\right\rbrace 
$$ 

where $\Gamma(t,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4t}}$.

Comment: It looks right, but you can give a much more explicit formula.

Comment: I've been using $\mathcal{F}(f(x))=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-ix\cdot k} dx$ for Fourier transform, and $\mathcal{F^{-1}}(f(k))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(k)e^{ik\cdot k} dk$. So taking the FT and solving it I get

$$ \mathcal{F}(u(t,x))=e^{i|k|^2t}\delta(k-\xi_0)$$

Then taking the inverse FT I get

$$u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(u))=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i|k|^2t\delta(k-\xi_0)e^{ik\cdot x}}dx\\
=e^{i|\xi_0|^2t}e^{i\xi_0\cdot x}
$$

How does that look? I tried it for  $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and it worked out.